# What is the best library development process while working with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm about to share an open source layout library that I'm writing, and I've decided to go with TypeScript! (It's the best thing out there!)

My library uses Easeljs, and PIXI libraries that you can find on definitelytyped.

I'm using TSD to get the latest *.d.ts files to get the latest definitions, so my "defs" folder looks like this (tweenjs is beeing used by easeljs):

[image]

The tsd.d.ts file is just one definitions file to include all the defs folder files, for better organization.

The problems start at development time.
On the grunt file I have a build task that will create a final js file in the "build" folder, that includes my library's definitions file, eventually it will result in this:
[image]

The problem is that in the **simple-layout.js.d.ts** there's only one reference to the tsd.d.ts, and NOT to the references to easeljs.d.ts and pixi.d.ts

I can not share this .d.ts file in definitelytyped, because it's referencing tsd.d.ts!

So, what is the best library development process while working with TypeScript?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't have a good automated workflow for this yet. 
Another thing that's keeping me back is the inability of `tsc` to generate a `.d.ts` for a project that uses external modules exclusively (which is what I think all projects should do)

Comment: FYI the plan is for this `.d.ts` *not* to be shared on DT but use `package.json` to point to the TypeScript definition.

Answer (score 0):

A good workflow for me is:

1. Create an empty project for TS code in WebStorm.
2. Create an Grunt configuration file for project.
3. Write a code and compile it only with Grunt - so project will be IDE-independent.
4. Write tests for project with QUnit (with DefinitelyTyped declaration) or with TSUnit and run it with GruntJS (for example, with PhantomJS backend).